# javascript canvas not drawing line in one unusual scenario

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

Sorry for my english. I don't speak it well at all.
I'm designing a chart library for practicing with canvas. I send it a json with the data to draw and the config options. I'm inserting that json below:

```
function drawChart() {
    let canvas = document.querySelector("#canvas")
    var chart = new Chartest(canvas, {
        chart: {
            type: Chartest.Line,
            style: {
                background: "#fff",
                barBackground: "#456"
            },
            title: "Unidades"
        },
        data: [{
                val: 10600,
                label: "Unidad 1"
            }, {
                val: 6000,
                label: "Segunda Unidad"
            }, {
                val: 4000,
                label: "Unidad numero tres"
            }, {
                val: 4005,
                label: "u4"
            }, {
                val: 0,
                label: "u5"
            }, {
                val: 50,
                label: "u6"
            }, {
                val: 3400,
                label: "u7"
         }]
    })
}
```

I draw a line from the current point to the predecessor point and so. Everything works fine except when I send a point with value 0. Then the line with the predecessor point doesn't draw. I'm logging the drawing point and everything seems to be correctly. Here you have the logged info and the final result where you can see, It's a missing line and I can't understand why:

[Img: Logged info and final result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gk4zX.png)

I'm inserting the part of my code when I draw the lines below:

```
for (let i = 0; i < this.config.data.length; i++) {
                // line type
                ctx.beginPath()
                let scaledPointVal = this.config.data[i].val * scaledUnitVal
                let gradient = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, absoluteGridTop - scaledPointVal, 0, absoluteGridTop)
                gradient.addColorStop(0, 'rgba(10, 20, 200, .85)')
                gradient.addColorStop(.7, 'rgba(10, 20, 200, .7)')
                ctx.strokeStyle = gradient
                ctx.lineWidth = 2
                ctx.closePath()
                let x = scaleSpaceWidth + spaceForEachOne * i
                if (i != 0
                    && !isNaN(parseFloat(this.config.data[i - 1].val)) && isFinite(this.config.data[i - 1].val)
                    && !isNaN(parseFloat(this.config.data[i].val)) && isFinite(this.config.data[i].val)) {
                    // last and current point available
                    // draw current point
                    let pointYPos = headerHeight + chartContainerHeight - scaledPointVal
                    ctx.beginPath()
                    ctx.rect(x + spaceForEachOne / 2 - 2, pointYPos - 2, 4, 4)
                    ctx.fill()
                    /////////////////////////////////////////////////
                    // line from last point to current
                    /////////////////////////////////////////////////
                    ctx.closePath()
                    ctx.beginPath()
                    ctx.moveTo(this.fixPixelPos(x + spaceForEachOne / 2), this.fixPixelPos(pointYPos))
                    ctx.lineTo(this.fixPixelPos(x - spaceForEachOne / 2),
                        this.fixPixelPos(headerHeight + chartContainerHeight - this.config.data[i - 1].val * scaledUnitVal))
                    console.log(`from ${this.fixPixelPos(x + spaceForEachOne / 2)}, ${this.fixPixelPos(pointYPos)}. to ${this.fixPixelPos(x - spaceForEachOne / 2)}, ${this.fixPixelPos(headerHeight + chartContainerHeight - this.config.data[i - 1].val * scaledUnitVal)}`);
                    ctx.stroke()
                    ctx.closePath()
                    //////////////////////////////////////////////////
                    //////////////////////////////////////////////////
                }
                else if (!isNaN(parseFloat(this.config.data[i].val)) && isFinite(this.config.data[i].val)) {
                    // first point or last not valid or empty. just draw current point
                    let pointYPos = headerHeight + chartContainerHeight - scaledPointVal
                    ctx.beginPath()
                    ctx.rect(x + spaceForEachOne / 2 - 2, pointYPos - 2, 4, 
                      4)
                    ctx.fill()
                    ctx.closePath()
                }
                ctx.beginPath()
                ctx.font = "12.5px Barlow"
                ctx.textAlign = "center"
                let text = this.config.data[i].label
                while (ctx.measureText(text).width > spaceForEachOne - 15)
                text = text.slice(0, text.length - 1)
                if (text.length < this.config.data[i].label.length)
                text += "..."
                ctx.fillText(text, x + spaceForEachOne / 2, headerHeight + 
                     chartContainerHeight + 20)
}
```

Please help me.

Comment: The problem is the line `let gradient = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, absoluteGridTop - scaledPointVal, 0, absoluteGridTop)` The y height of the gradient when `scaledPointVal` is zero (from `absoluteGridTop - scaledPointVal`, to `absoluteGridTop`) is zero and that is not a valid gradient. You need to make sure that the distance betweent the two gradient points is greater than 0.

Comment: Thanks a lot! that was the problem. How can I mark your answer as the correct one?